# Need help connecting skeleton to model

Tags: armature, bones

I have downloaded an .fbx file and when I open it the 'bones' are not exactly bones and they're not connected to the model.
The 'bones' are in a hierarchy and I think they're not the right object type (I'm unsure what they are)

[image: Here is the model and the bones]

[image: Here is what the objects look like in the collection container]

I've tried to look in the documentation but I can not figure out how to convert this structure into bones and how to connect it to the model.

My final goal in the end is to apply gravity on this model so it rag-dolls to the floor.

Answer (score 0):

There's an addon made for converting empties into bones, available in paid and free versions:

- 5.0$ : [Empties To Bones - Blender Market](https://blendermarket.com/products/empties-to-bones)
- Free : [artellblender/empties_to_bones](https://github.com/artellblender/empties_to_bones)

You could use this to generate the armature, then parent it to the mesh via <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Armature Deform With Automatic Weights.